# Wrong value in ST_distance between two lines

Tags: qgis, postgis

I have two geometries (MULTILINESTRING, type 4326). I load them (a sql database with these values) in QGIS and their distance is around 4km (I checked it with the original file in kml).

[image: Distance betwen two lines]

When I measure the distance between them throught PostGIS and I got a wrong value:

```
select st_distance('0105000020E6100000010000000102000000020000000000000048A057C06E352565BCA1414000000000880855C02737039CC94E4240'::geography, '0105000020E6100000010000000102000000020000000000000078F757C04DE67241D707444000000000885157C037F73119779E3E40'::geography)
```

It returns 0 instead of 4 or 4000

Comment: Consider replacing `::geography` with `::geometry(MultiLineString)`.

Comment: @user30184 you are right, I will remove my comment.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

With the PostGIS `geography` data type, each pair of points along a `LineString` defines a great circle arc, not a straight segment in a Cartesian plane. And the two arcs defined by your inputs intersect, hence the reported distance of zero.

To visualize this, you can use the `ST_Segmentize` function to add more vertices along your geographies. When you do this, the shape of the arc becomes apparent and you can see the intersection of the geographies. [image]:

Comment: And how can I get the answer 4 km? I need to modify something?

Comment: `ST_Length(ST_ShortestLine(geom_a, geom_b)::geography)`

Comment: Thanks, I used ST_Segmentize to solve it too, but it gives me 3.980 km instead of 4.006 km. How I can get the same values with both methods?
select st_distance(ST_Segmentize('0105000020E6100000010000000102000000020000000000000048A057C06E352565BCA1414000000000880855C02737039CC94E4240'::geometry,1)::geography, ST_Segmentize('0105000020E6100000010000000102000000020000000000000078F757C04DE67241D707444000000000885157C037F73119779E3E40'::geometry,1)::geography)/1000